# MySQL Master Slave replication error 1032

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have enabled MySQL Master-Slave replication, but unfortunately getting the following error.

```
Last_SQL_Errno: 1032
Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Update_rows event on table XXXXXXX; Can’t find record in ‘txn_re’port_accrual_redemption, Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event’s master log mysql-bin.000119, end_log_pos 12537772
```

Comment: very both server tables - Count(*) from both server.

Comment: After troubleshooting for long I'm getting the following error now.